# How to implement Push-Based Architectures when I click on the button in angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I learn about Push-Based Architectures with RxJS and Angular.

From what I learned I understood that Pull-Base architectures is when the view is calling to get the data.

This can be using obserables or by assignment:

```
 users$ = this.facade.users$

 loadUser() { this.facade.loadUser(); }
```

In the facade:

```
 users$ = new BeahviorSubject();

 loadUser() { this.http.get('...').subscribe(users => { this.users$.next(users); }) }
```

In Push-Base it should react to changes like:

```
  search = new FormControl();

  search.valueChanges().pipe(tap(searchTerm => searchSomething(searchTerm)));
```

This is good when it's comes to events. but what if I need to "react" to click on the button?

Basically the button save "pull" the data. So I'm confuse about this and it will be helpful if someone can solve this conflict.

Answer (score 1):

While the component still triggers a "push" event on button click, the effect of the event can happen reactively.

Using the example of a very basic search form...

---

Service File

```
private searchTerm = new Subject<string>();

public searchResult$ = this.searchTerm.pipe(
  switchMap(searchTerm =>
    this.http.get<string[]>(`url?${searchTerm}`)
  ),
  startWith([])
);

public newSearchTerm = (newTerm:string) => {
  this.searchTerm.next(newTerm);
}
```

We declare a private subject that will emit our search query.

Next we declare the observable that will take the emitted search query, and will plug that into our HTTP request. We can return the http request since that returns an observable of the response.

Since the `searchTerm` subject doesn't emit anything at the beginning, we add our initial value (an empty array) with the operator `startWith()`.

Last, we create a public method that allows other classes to emit the next search term.

---

Component TS File

```
public searchInput = new FormControl('');

public searchResult$ = this.service.searchResult$;

public searchEvent = () => {
  this.service.newSearchTerm(searchInput.value);
}
```

We declare our FormControl search input as you did in your example.

Next, we subscribe to the `searchResult$` observable from our service. Again, this is relying on that service subject to emit a search term.

Last, we create a method to handle the button click event. While the method returns void, it will invoke the service method to emit a new search term.

This will cause our component's state `searchResult$` to react, displaying the value returned from the service HTTP request.

---

Component HTML File

```
<input formControlName="searchInput" />
<button (click)="searchEvent()">Search</button>

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let result of searchResult$ | async">{{ result }}</li>
</ul>
```

Lastly, we setup our HTML. The button output will invoke the `searchEvent()` method. And we use the `async` pipe to subscribe to `searchResult$`. This puts the entire observable chain into one single subscription in this view. When the component is destroyed (on screen change), it will cause the entire observable chain to unsubscribe.